# Regex to get text in a sentence

Tags: php, regex

Below is one of my message in language configuration. I want to detect possible words to be randomly choosen to display for users.

What is the regex, to detect the possibility of random word as I bold

> **[Bravo|Great|Congratulation|Well done|Hoorey|Yeehaa|Wow]**! You are now to top to be a winner. Keep going!

Development in Php

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your use of the word "detect".

Comment: `/(Bravo|Great|Congratulation|Well done|Hoorey|Yeehaa|Wow)! You are now to top to be a winner\. Keep going!/`

Comment: Why don't you simply use [`^[^!]+(?=!)`](https://regex101.com/r/alMebD/1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/alMebD/1)

```
^[^!]+(?=!)
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
Bravo! You are now to top to be a winner. Keep going!
Great! You are now to top to be a winner. Keep going!
Congratulations! You are now to top to be a winner. Keep going!
Well done! You are now to top to be a winner. Keep going!
Hooray! You are now to top to be a winner. Keep going!
Yeehaa! You are now to top to be a winner. Keep going!
Wow! You are now to top to be a winner. Keep going!
```

#### Output

```
Bravo
Great
Congratulations
Well done
Hoorey
Yeehaa
Wow
```

### Explanation

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `[^!]+` Match any character except `!` one or more times
- `(?=!)` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows matches `!` literally

Answer (score 0):

To *choose a word for display*, I'm not sure you need regex. I would do something like this:

```
function getMessage () {
    $words = ["Bravo","Great","Congratulations","Well done","Hoorey","Yeehaa","Wow"];
    return $words [rand (0, count ($words) - 1] . "! You are now to top to be a winner. Keep going!";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But this is the last choice because there are so many text to manage provided by content provider.